# Log a total value calculated with async callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I write something like the code below, I get the total btye size value each time a file is added. How can I log out only the total files size, after it's calculated in the fs.stat callback?

```js
var fs = require('fs');

var totalBytes = 0;

function calcTotalSize(){
    //I read the files in the dir
    fs.readdir(".",function(err,files){

        files.forEach(function(filename,index) {

            fs.stat("./" + filename,function(err,stats){
                totalBytes += stats.size;
                console.log(totalBytes); // like this it logs the total updated for each items in the files array
            });    
        });
    });

    //-- log out the totalBytes --
}

calcTotalSize();
```

PS: I want to do it using only async functions, and not with if(i == files.length) condition if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print out the total when it's done using async fs.stat(), you need something you can control the async flow, such as async module (don't forget to install it: 'npm install async').  Here is the revised code using async.each():

```
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');

function calcTotalSize(){
    var totalBytes = 0;
    //I read the files in the dir
    fs.readdir(".",function(err,files){
        async.each(files, function(filename, eachCb) {
            fs.stat("./" + filename,function(err,stats){
                totalBytes += stats.size;
                eachCb(null);
            });
        }, function(err) {
            console.log('DONE: %d', totalBytes);
        });
    });
}

calcTotalSize();
```

Comment: Thank you Ben for your solution. To improve my understanding, what's the meaning of eachCb(null)?

Comment: It's async.each()'s callback.  It's required to be called for each iteration of the loop to signal async.each() to continue on.  If this callback is not call, async.each() won't contunue to process the rest of the items (files).  each(null) with null as an argument means that there is no error and continue on with next iteration.  If you pass in a non-null/undefined value.  async.each() will stop processing the rest of the items.  So if fs.stat() returns an error in the callback (err), and you don't want to continue, then call eachCb(err) instead of eachCb(null)/eachCb().

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of 3 choices (I've put it in my order of preference):

1. Use `promises` for getting a callback when all stats are calculated.
2. Use `fs.statSync`
3. Keep track of how many files you've read and output the sum when reached the total of files

Since **2** and **3** are straightforward, I'll show you how to implement **1** using [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) promise library (there are [others](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) similar), should look like :

```
fs.readdir(".",function(err,files){
        var promises = [];

        files.forEach(function(filename,index) {
            var fsStatPromise = Q.nfcall(fs.stat, "./" + filename);
            promises.push(fsStatPromise);    
        });

        Q.all(promises).then(function(results) { 
            var total = results.reduce(function(a, b) {
                return a.size + b.size;
            });
            console.log(total); 
        }, function(err) {
           console.log(err);
        });
    });
```

The benefit of using `promises` vs `fs.statSync` here is that you don't loose the performance of `async io`, which WILL make a difference depending on how many files you are reading...

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your very detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

You're encountering this probem because `readdir` and `stat` are both async functions. The easiest way to fix this is to use `readdirSync` and `statSync`.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of the total files readed, e.g:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var totalBytes = 0;
var filesReaded = 0;

function calcTotalSize(){
    fs.readdir(".",function(err,files){

        files.forEach(function(filename,index) {

            fs.stat("./" + filename,function(err,stats){
                totalBytes += stats.size;
                if (++filesReaded === files.length)
                  console.log(totalBytes); // log only when all the files were readed
            });    
        });
    });
}

calcTotalSize();
```